# TypeScript create a dictionary of a type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create a dictionary in TypeScript where each element in the dictionary is of a class type.

```
interface Methods {
    [index: string]: MethodRep;
}

export class MethodRep {
    name: string;
}

export class BaseFileStructure {
    public methods: Methods;

    constructor() {
        this.methods = {};
    }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to like it. I'm using atom with a TypeScript pluging. it says `Compile failed but emit succeeded`.

If I change the type of the elements to string then it works (even putting type number doesn't work)

```
interface Methods {
    [index: string]: string; // only this works
}
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: Typescript playground (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground) doesn't show any errors for your code.

Comment: Have you tried to change your MethodRep class to an interface ?

Comment: Agreed with @Guillaume I've only ever got this to work with interfaces

Answer (score 1):

Since `interface Methods` is not exported, but you are using it as part of a class that *is* exported, if your compiler is set up to create declaration (d.ts) files (and it’s possible that the plugin you are using always does this behind the scenes and manages writing these files itself), TypeScript will complain that the interface Methods is not exported because it is referenced by a publicly accessible member:

> error TS4031: Public property 'methods' of exported class has or is using private name 'Methods'.

If you change `interface Methods` to `export interface Methods`, this should solve the problem, since there is otherwise no problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with replacing `MethodRep` class to an interface like this :

```
interface Methods {
    [index: string]: MethodRep;
}

export interface MethodRep {
    name: string;
}

export class BaseFileStructure {
    public methods: Methods;

    constructor() {
        this.methods = {};
    }
}
```